# vb6 how to check an empty value in mysql

Tags: mysql, vb6

i want to check selected value in the table if it null/empty or not null, but it always go to else state that value is not empty, even though value in hdf_file table is empty.

```vb
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim fld As ADODB.Field

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" & "SERVER=localhost;" & " DATABASE=etl;" & "UID=root;PWD=;"
conn.Open
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM hdf_file WHERE NAMA_FILE = ' " & get_nama_file & " ' ", conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
If IsEmpty(rs.Fields(2).Value) Then
'Insert ke tabel hdf_file
    Debug.Print "EMPTY"
Else
    Debug.Print "NOT EMPTY"
End If
```

i also tried this:

```vb
If IsEmpty(rs.Fields(2).Value) Then
```

but i got error, it said that: either BOF and EOF is true, or the current record has been deleted, etc..

Comment: The error is telling you that the query did not return any records. The is not a record to read a value from.

Comment: @jac ok, thnk u, but how do i check is null/empty records without error? so i can put line code in 'if' or 'else' statement ? sorry i'm newbee in using vb6, please tell me the detail solution..

Answer (score 2):

You should check to make sure your recordset isn't empty before you attempt to read records from it. You can do this by testing the `EOF` property. If your query returned records, you can then test a specific column for `NULL` by using the `IsNull()` function. Finally, you can omit `Fields` and `Value` when querying a column, since `Fields` is the default property of a `Recordset` object and `Value` is the default property of a `Field`. So the following:

```vb
rs.Fields(2).Value
```

can be written instead as:

```vb
rs(2)
```

For example:

```vb
' Run query...
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM hdf_file WHERE NAMA_FILE = ' " & get_nama_file & " ' ", conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

' Ensure recordset is not empty...
If Not rs.EOF Then

    ' Test column 3 for NULL...
    If IsNull(rs(2)) Then
        Debug.Print "Column is NULL"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Column is NOT NULL"
    End If

End If
```

Comment: i've tried to  use `if Not rs.EOF` but it always return EOF even though WHERE NAMA_FILE = ' " & get_nama_file & "' is true exist in the table...

Comment: Then there must be something wrong with your SQL statement. Use `Debug.Print` to output your SQL statement. Then copy/paste it into a query window and run it to see if it returns records.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably in this line:

```
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM hdf_file WHERE NAMA_FILE = ' " & get_nama_file & " ' ", conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

You have added extra spaces between the single quotes and the double quotes that delineate the VB string. Try:

```
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM hdf_file WHERE NAMA_FILE = '" & get_nama_file & "'", conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

Comment: That seems highly likely, given that a file name isn't typically going to be preceded and followed by a space.